# Search function doesn't work any more

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have SharePoint 2010 installed and I have 3 Site Collections running at this farm. Search function is working with 2 Site collection but not with the 3rd one. Everything is working fine except the search. I have thousands of documents, tasks, announcements etc), however whenever I search the site using the defaul search, i get nothing returned no matter what i search on, I simply get "We did not find any results for [search term]". The search box is not always clickable.
Please assist me to solve the problem.

Best regards
//Ashraf